# How can I create Table in TeX and get information from txt file

Tags: tables, external-files

How may I input `.txt` file to the TeX `tabular`?
I have a list of students (FirstName, LastName, and if this student was at
school). 0 means not, 1 means yes, of course...

`.txt` file look like this:

```
\r Julo:Petrzlen:011:100:101:

\r Ivan:Hrasok:110:101:010:
```

0 had to look like this "-" and 1 "x" in `tabular`.

I am beginner in TeX and programming at all... I really have no idea how to start. So please, help me.

Comment: Can you also explain what `011:100:101` stands for? Are there nine schools?

Comment: Have a look at the [`pgfplotstable` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) (Yes the heading on that page is incorrect!)

Comment: 011:100:101 - there is nine lessons at school, 0 and 1 means presence

Comment: You may want to check out package `datatool`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Can be solved with some TeX magic:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
\r Julo:Petrzlen:011:100:101:
\r Ivan:Hrasok:110:101:010:
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{array}
\def\Conv#1#2#3!!{%
  \ifnum#1=0 -\else x\fi \ifnum#2=0 -\else x\fi \ifnum#3=0 -\else x\fi}
\def\r#1:#2:#3:#4:#5:{#1 & #2 & \Conv#3!! & \Conv#4!! & \Conv#5!! \\}
% !! marks the end of input
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *3{>{\ttfamily}l} @{}}\hline
  \emph{Firstname} & \emph{Lastname} & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\\hline 
  \input{data.txt}
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And the same for a short firstname:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
\r Julo:Petrzlen:011:100:101:
\r Ivan:Hrasok:110:101:010:
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{array}
\def\Short#1#2!!{#1. }
\def\Conv#1#2#3!!{%
  \ifnum#1=0 -\else x\fi \ifnum#2=0 -\else x\fi \ifnum#3=0 -\else x\fi}
\def\r#1:#2:#3:#4:#5:{\Short#1!! #2 & \Conv#3!! & \Conv#4!! & \Conv#5!! \\}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *3{>{\ttfamily}l} @{}}\hline
  \emph{name} & \ldots & \ldots & \ldots\\\hline 
  \input{data.txt}
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And, last but not least, all courses in an own column (`\Conv` now writes 3 columns.)!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.txt}
\r Julo:Petrzlen:011:100:101:
\r Ivan:Hrasok:110:101:010:
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{array}
\def\Short#1#2!!{#1. }
\def\Conv#1#2#3!!{%
  \ifnum#1=0 -\else x\fi & \ifnum#2=0 -\else x\fi & \ifnum#3=0 -\else x\fi}
\def\r#1:#2:#3:#4:#5:{\Short#1!! #2 & \Conv#3!! & \Conv#4!! & \Conv#5!! \\}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{} l *9{>{\ttfamily}l} @{}}\hline
  \emph{name} & \multicolumn{9}{c}{\ldots}\\\hline 
  \input{data.txt}
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much... this is exactly what I need.
And I am not sure about this
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *3{>{\ttfamily}l} @{}}
please, may you explain me what does it means? Thanks a lot

Comment: `@{}`: no extra space on the left and right. `*3{..}`: three identical columns in typewriter font. Change it to whatever you need

Comment: Thank you. And what if I would like to have Lastname and Firstname together, Lastname will be first and  Firstname will be not Julo but just J. ?

Comment: see my edited answer.

Comment: What means "x and - separate"? If its in own tabular columns then use `\def\Conv#1#2#3!!{%
  \ifnum#1=0 -\else x\fi & \ifnum#2=0 -\else x\fi &  \ifnum#3=0 -\else x\fi}`  and add the columns in the tabular hedaer.

Comment: Thank you. <br/> And I have one more question. I want to have x and - separate. not three in the group . I was trying but I have something wrong ... \def\Conv#1!!{% \ifnum#1=1 x \else - \fi } \def\r#1:#2:#3#4#5:#6#7#8:#9#10#11:{ #2 \Short#1!! & \Conv#3!! & \Conv#4!! & \Conv#5!! & \Conv#6!! & \Conv#7!! & \Conv#8!! & \Conv#9!! & \Conv#10!! & \Conv#11!! \\} ... \begin{tabular}{||l| *9{>{\textsf}c} ||}\hline atc

Comment: If you mean in own columns then use: `\def\Conv#1#2#3!!{
  \ifnum#1=0 -\else x\fi & \ifnum#2=0 -\else x\fi &  \ifnum#3=0 -\else x\fi}` and add the columns in the tabular header. Let the macros `\r` and `\short` unchanged.

Comment: see my comment. There is no need for a counter ...

Comment: And there is error. In .txt file: " Paragraph ended before \r was complete" . in .tex : "You already have nine parameters \def\r#1:#2:#3#4#5:#6#7#8:#9#10#1" . Conv is yours, r is the same like in my comment.

Comment: didn't you read what I wrote?? `\r` should _not_ be changed!! By the way, there are only 9 parameters possible.

Comment: We miss understand. I expressed badly. I have to count all lessons with 1 for each student. So I tought that I need own tabular columns for each 0 and 1. What can I do, if I need more than 9 parameters???

Comment: you do _not_ need more. see my third example in the answer

Answer (score 3):

For reference, here is one version using `pgfplotstable`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=colon,columns={First,Last,Mon,Tue,Wed},
string type,string replace*={0}{\(- \)},string replace*={1}{\(+ \)}]{students.txt}

\end{document}
```

with `students.txt`:

```
First:Last:Mon:Tue:Wed: 
Julo:Petrzlen:011:100:101:
Ivan:Hrasok:110:101:010:
```

If the first two columns could contain zeros and ones, then you would have to limit the substitutions.  The following makes specifications for each column separately, and shows how to left align the first columns:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[col sep=colon,columns={First,Last,Mon,Tue,Wed},
string type,
columns/First/.style={column type=l},
columns/Last/.style={column type=l},
columns/Mon/.style={string replace*={0}{\(- \)},string replace*={1}{\(+ \)}},
columns/Tue/.style={string replace*={0}{\(- \)},string replace*={1}{\(+ \)}},
columns/Wed/.style={string replace*={0}{\(- \)},string replace*={1}{\(+ \)}}%
]{students.txt}

\end{document}
```